Which command can I use to open Visual Studio from command line and start building solution in x64-Release
I found the following command-line in order to open the visual studio and start building it.
However, I could not find how to specify the configuration and platform.
devenv YourSolution.sln /command "Build.BuildSolution"
Could you please help me?

Use the following command assuming you are working on C# project:
MsBuild SolutionPath\Solution.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x64"

